# testing contract inside smartpy test initializing by contract address

Tags: smartpy

While testing on smart contract file by adding scenario,

```
@sp.add_test("IntegrationTest")
def test():
    sc = sp.test_scenario()
         helper_contract = deploy_helper_contract()
         sc += helper_contract
         helper_contract.originatContract()
```

this function originateContract of helper, originates a new contract (contractB) from a smart contract,
Now I need to do some test on the originated contract (ContractB) from the test.
I have the address of the new originated contract i.e contractB.

How do I call the functions of contract B inside test scenario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Contracts](https://smartpy.io/manual/scenarios/testing_contracts#dynamic-contracts). It is a way to retrieve the contract instances that are originated from other contracts while running in a scenario.

It takes three arguments:

- `contractId` is the ID of the originated dynamic contract. It starts from 0 and keeps incrementing.
- `tcontract` is the contract class
- `tparameter` is the parameter type of the contract.

```
import smartpy as sp


class ContractB(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)


class ContractA(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)
        self.contractB = ContractB()

    @sp.entry_point
    def create_b(self):
        sp.create_contract(self.contractB, storage=())


@sp.add_test(name = "Dynamic Contract")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    contractA = ContractA()
    scenario += contractA
    scenario += contractA.contractB

    admin = sp.test_account('admin')
    contractA.create_b().run(sender = admin)

    contractB = scenario.dynamic_contract(0, contractA.contractB)
    scenario.h1('ContractB Retrieved')
    scenario.show(contractB.address)
```